# How to model customer satisfaction when customer satisfaction is a binary variable?

Tags: anova, factor-analysis

I want to see if certain factors affect overall customer satisfaction for a specific program. My response would be customer satisfaction ratings, where a **0=not satisfied** and **1=satisfied**. If my factors follow the same scale, can I use a factorial design to test whether the factors have an affect on the overall customer satisfaction?

Comment: Hi Stats and welcome to the site! With an outcome taking only two values, 0 and 1, [logistic regression](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/logit.htm) is one possibility. Your outcome would be customer satisfaction and your other factors are the independent variables. How to do it concretely depends on your software. Just ask if you have further/more specific questions.

Answer (score 2):

Several points:

A factorial design is a technique for setting up an experiment.  You could only use it in this situation if you can randomly assign the factors to customers, which seems unlikely.

It doesn't matter whether the factors follow the same scale or not, but if you want a factorial design they do need to be factors ie categorical variables with defined levels (like red, blue, green; or suburb of origin; or something like that).

On the other hand, whether or not you need specifically to use a factorial design, as @COOLSerdash says logistic regression is probably the analytical technique you need.  Logistic regression is a legitimate technique whether or not you have an experiment, and whatever scales the explanatory variables are one.

Short answer - you probably can't do a factorial design, but you probably can use logistic regression.